# PHP Upgrade 5.1 to 5.4

Tags: centos, php, centos5

I've upgraded PHP on my CentOS 5.10 box.

I added the epel 5 repo and used yum to upgrade to PHP 5.4.21.

PHP was working fine before this, but since the upgrade it just spits on the code, it shows a blank page but when you view the source the PHP is there. I've tried restarting Apache but that made no effect.

Any ideas what else it could be?

Comment: Did you upgrade all the php packages on the system?

Comment: I upgraded php-common php-cli and a couple of others

Comment: `php -v` returns PHP 5.4.21 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2013 12:42:05) and phpinfo() doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove the following things from your php.ini? http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.ini.php